# Combining list entries into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, python-3.x

I am trying to get the first_name and last_name to combine together into a new dictionary entry. How many depends on how many people buy in the shop. If I buy 50 troops I always receive less than that.

```
import random, math
first_name = [ "Emily", "Steve" , "Dave" , "Bob" , "James" , "Jim" , "Jenny" , "Will" , "Ryan" ]
last_name = [ "Wright" , "Kalman" , "Meitzen" , "Cole" , "Robins" , "Harrison" , "Saturn" ]
troops = {}
money = 1000

def shop():
    loop = 0
    global money, first_name, last_name, troops
    while loop == 0 :
        print("""
        Your Money = {}
        (Number , Item , cost)
        0, Quit ,N/A
        1, Troop, 10
        """.format(money))
        shopq = int( input("What do you want to buy"))

        if shopq == 1:
            shopq2 = int( input("How many"))
            if shopq2 > money :
                print(" You cannot by this many")
            else:
                print("You can buy that many")
                money = money - shopq2
                troop_number = 0
                while troop_number < shopq2 :
                    s_name = random.choice(first_name) + " " + random.choice(last_name)
                    troops[s_name] = 100
                    troop_number = troop_number + 1
                print(troops)

            print(" Money = {}".format(money))
        elif shopq == 0:
            break

class dropship:
    def create(self, troops):
        troop_number = 0
        for k in troops :
            troop_number = troop_number + 1
        print("troops = {}".format(troop_number))

shop()
x = dropship()
x.create(troops)
```

Output:

```
        Your Money = 1000
        (Number , Item , cost)
        0, Quit ,N/A
        1, Troop, 10

What do you want to buy1
How many50
You can buy that many
{'Ryan Wright': 100, 'Bob Cole': 100, 'Bob Kalman': 100, 'Will Wright': 100, 'Dave Cole': 100, 'Dave Robins': 100, 'Emily Kalman': 100, 'Jenny Kalman': 100, 'Bob Harrison': 100, 'Emily Wright': 100, 'Will Cole': 100, 'Jim Wright': 100, 'Dave Kalman': 100, 'Dave Wright': 100, 'Bob Meitzen': 100, 'Jenny Wright': 100, 'Jenny Harrison': 100, 'Dave Saturn': 100, 'James Robins': 100, 'Bob Robins': 100, 'Dave Meitzen': 100, 'Steve Wright': 100, 'Bob Wright': 100, 'Steve Kalman': 100, 'Ryan Harrison': 100, 'Jim Saturn': 100, 'Steve Robins': 100, 'Ryan Cole': 100, 'Jim Meitzen': 100, 'James Cole': 100, 'Emily Cole': 100, 'Ryan Saturn': 100, 'Steve Harrison': 100}
 Money = 950

        Your Money = 950
        (Number , Item , cost)
        0, Quit ,N/A
        1, Troop, 10

What do you want to buy0
troops = 33
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4):

You are creating random names and some of them will be the same, by chance, so they replace the previous entries in the dictionary (dictionary keys are unique). You'll have to change the way you do that. For instance:

```
import random
import itertools
random.sample(list(itertools.product(first_name, last_name)), 50)
```

But you should also get much larger pools of first and last names, otherwise you can only have 63 different full names.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your dictionary is that dictionary keys must be unique. Since you are using randomly chosen names spliced together as keys, it is very likely that you will generate `'Ryan Wright'` (for example) more than once.

Here is what your code is doing that is causing you to come up with a "short" count:

```
troops['Ryan Wright'] = 100
troops['Bob Cole'] = 100
troops['Ryan Wright'] = 100
```

The third assignment used the same slot in the dictionary `troops` because the key is the same. If your code was just those three lines you'd have a dictionary with two entries in it, not the three that you'd hope for. You can see this happen in your code by adding the `assert` statement:

```
s_name = random.choice(first_name) + " " + random.choice(last_name)
assert s_name not in troops
troops[s_name] = 100
```

It won't fix your problem, but it will show you that your keys are colliding.